# Difference between "riddle" and "puzzle"

Tags: meaning, synonyms

What's the difference in using these synonym verbs.

What's difference in meaning of the following sentences? Could those verbs be used interchangeably?

> 1. I am riddled knowing there are so many potential Vicki Myers who do not have a Greg.
> 2. I am puzzled, as I think perhaps anybody watching and many of us here today are puzzled, by the characterization of this amendment as being in opposition to the President.

Update : the first sentence has been changed.

Comment: Check a dictionary. **Riddle** has two etymologically unrelated senses (puzzle, and *sieve*). In your context, *riddled* means *full of holes, shot to pieces*.

Comment: ...following your edit, the first version is no longer "normal" English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/riddle) :

> **riddle** <sub>(third-person singular simple present riddles, present participle riddling, simple past and past participle riddled)</sub>
>
> - To speak ambiguously or enigmatically.
> - (transitive) To solve, answer, or explicate a riddle or question

[And](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/puzzle) :

> **puzzle** <sub>(third-person singular simple present puzzles, present participle puzzling, simple past and past participle puzzled)</sub>
>
> - (transitive) To perplex (someone).
> - To make intricate; to entangle.

The first meaning from riddle is **only about speaking** while the second meaning of puzzle is about **any action being complexified and raising curiosity**.

Comment: " Puzzle is something on reality and not on guessing", from https://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100209065230AAL1QtM

Comment: "...adding some mist??!!  What do you mean by that?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I wanted to say that the action is not easily understandable using the meaning of mist : "Anything that dims or darkens". I can replace *"some mist"* by *"complexity"* if you prefer.

Comment: Oh, I get it now.  I was completely baffled. Yes, I think  "complexity" says it better.

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I wanted to add some fantasy :'(

Comment: @BrianHitchcock Is it ok now?

Comment: Yes. I like your use of  "complexified"!